# How to sort a table with imported JSON data

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, html-table, getjson

I have a JSON file with list of employes. I imported this data to table. Next step is add sorting by `<th>`. My script doesn't work and nothing happens. I don't know the reason. I'm just a JS beginner. Can You help me why sorting is not working?

Here is my repository:
https://github.com/rrajca/Employee-table

My js is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("dane.json", function(data) {
        /* var sortedList = data.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.id - b.id;
          }) */
        var employeeList = "";
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            employeeList += "<tr>";
            employeeList += "<td>"+value.id+"</td>";
            employeeList += "<td>"+value.firstName+"</td>";
            employeeList += "<td>"+value.lastName+"</td>";
            employeeList += "<td>"+value.dateOfBirth+"</td>";
            employeeList += "<td>"+value.company+"</td>";
            employeeList += "<td>"+value.note+"</td>";
            employeeList += "</tr>";
        })
        $("tbody").append(employeeList);
    })

    var compare = {
        name: function(a, b) {
            a = a.replace(/^the /i, '');
            b = b.replace(/^the /i, '');

            if (a < b) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return a > b ? 1 : 0;
            }
        },
        duration: function(a, b) {
            a = a.split(':');
            b = b.split(':');

            a = Number(a[0]) * 60 + Number(a[1]);
            b = Number(b[0]) * 60 + Number(b[1]);

            return a - b;
        },
        date: function(a, b) {
            a = new Date(a);
            b = new Date(b);

            return a - b;
        }
    };

    $('.sortable').each(function() {
        var $table = $(this);
        var $tbody = $table.find('tbody');
        var $controls = $table.find('th');
        var rows = $tbody.find('tr').toArray();

        $controls.on('click', function() {
            var $header = $(this);
            var order = $header.data('sort');
            var column;

            if ($header.is('.ascending') || $header.is('.descending')) {  
                $header.toggleClass('ascending descending');
                $tbody.append(rows.reverse());
            } else {
                $header.addClass('ascending');
                $header.siblings().removeClass('ascending descending'); 
                if (compare.hasOwnProperty(order)) {
                    column = $controls.index(this);

                    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
                        a = $(a).find('td').eq(column).text();
                        b = $(b).find('td').eq(column).text();
                        return compare[order](a, b);
                        });

                $tbody.append(rows);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your comparison function to:

```
name: function(a, b) {                  // Add a method called name
      a = a.replace(/^the /i, '');          // Remove The from start of parameter
      b = b.replace(/^the /i, '');          // Remove The from start of parameter
      if(parseInt(a) == +a) {
        a = +a;
        b = +b;            
      }     
      return a > b          
    }
```

The problem was that you were doing string comparisons on everything. So I added in a check to see if it was a number, and casted appropriately.

https://jsfiddle.net/gj2vonsL/7/

The other comparison functions that you wrote have other issues like invalid date formats, etc. But your general idea is correct

Comment: Thanks for answer. I noticed when i use:

`$.getJSON("dane.json", function(data) {`

sorting is still not working. But when i copy json file dane.json and past it to js like you:
<pre>
`data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "Jan",
  "lastName": "Kowalski",
  "dateOfBirth": "1.7.1990 11:35",
  "company": "XSolve",
  "note": 90
 }, ...`

sorting is working! I dont know why is this happening. Why i cant just import json file by getJson and sort this data?

Comment: Sorry I thought you were just fixing the incorrect sort. (Sorry I can't update the jsfiddle with getJSON. However, the crux of your problem is the asynchronous nature of javascript. In your code, 

`var rows = $tbody.find('tr').toArray()`

is being executed before $.getJSON is returning. and so your rows array is blank when you're doing the click event (it's being taken from an external scope and only executed once). The simplest way to fix this is to put that line into the click handler.

Once you do that, you can fix your sort functions